# How to wrap a function from an inherited class to add functionality, similarly to Python decorators

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm inheriting a more generic health handling class to add functionality specific to the player. I wish to decorate functions inherited from the old class in a similar manner to Python decorators to add checks and functionality when they are called, hopefully without rewriting the existing functions.

For clarity I've included the two classes below:

```
public class HealthSystem
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    public int currentHealth;
    public int maxHealth;

    // Update is called once per frame

    public HealthSystem(int maxHealth, int currentHealth = 0)
    {
        if (currentHealth == 0) this.currentHealth = maxHealth;
        else this.currentHealth = currentHealth;
        this.maxHealth = maxHealth;
    }
    public int Damage(int damageAmount)
    {
        currentHealth -= damageAmount;
        if (currentHealth < 0) currentHealth = 0;

        return currentHealth;
    }

    public int Heal(int healAmount)
    {
        currentHealth += healAmount;
        if (currentHealth > maxHealth) currentHealth = maxHealth;

        return currentHealth;
    }

    public void SetMaxHealth(int newMaxHealth)
    {
        maxHealth = newMaxHealth;
    }

    public void UpdateMaxHealth(int updateAmount)
    { 
        maxHealth += updateAmount;
    }

    public void SetCurrentHealth(int newCurrentHealth)
    {
        currentHealth = newCurrentHealth;
    }

    

    }
```

Currently I'm inheriting this HealthSystem Class into a Player Health System Class, Which is functionally very similar except it also takes a reference to the gameObject that instantiates it.

```
public class PlayerHealthSystem : HealthSystem
{
    private GameObject parent;
    public PlayerHealthSystem(int maxHealth, GameObject parent, int currentHealth = 0) : base(maxHealth, currentHealth)
    {
        this.parent = parent;
    }
}

public class MyAttribute : Attribute
{ 

}
```

The point of this is that I want certain function calls that modify the current health to be checked after they've run to see if the players current health is 0, which would make a call back to the player gameObject to run some kind of death script. I wanted to do this with python-like decorators like so:

```
[HealthCheck]
func()

decorator HealthCheck()
{
    if (this.currentHealth == 0) 
    {
        parent.GetComponent<PlayerControl>.DeathScript();
    }
}
```

Can anyone provide an example of how to achieve it, I can see so many uses for this kind of pattern and it would be amazing to learn how to do it now so I can implement it later.

Comment: In .NET they are called attributes, so that's a whole subject for you to research.

Comment: @John Thank you for the help, Im new to c# and was pretty sure this was the direction to go , but the documentation is really confusing to a newbie, ill look into it now :)

Answer (score 1):

The way the [decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) is usually implemented in C# is by having an interface which both the decorator as well as the decorated class implement.

The decorator wraps an instance of the decorated class, and implements all members of the interface as pass-through calls to the wrapped object - along with some additional functionality on top.

```
public interface IHealthSystem
{
    int Damage(int damageAmount);
    int Heal(int healAmount);
    void SetCurrentHealth(int newCurrentHealth);
}

public class HealthSystemDecorator : IHealthSystem
{
    private readonly IHealthSystem wrappedHealthSystem;
    private readonly PlayerControl playerControl;
    
    public HealthSystemDecorator(IHealthSystem wrappedHealthSystem, PlayerControl playerControl)
    {
        this.wrappedHealthSystem = wrappedHealthSystem;
        this.playerControl = playerControl;
    }
    
    public void Damage()    
    {
        wrappedHealthSystem.Damage();
        HandleInvokeDeathScript();
    }
    
    public void Heal()
    {
        wrappedHealthSystem.Heal();
    }
    
    public void SetCurrentHealth(int newCurrentHealth)
    {
        wrappedHealthSystem.SetCurrentHealth(newCurrentHealth);
        HandleInvokeDeathScript();
    }
    
    private void HandleInvokeDeathScript()
    {
        if(currentHealth == 0) 
        {
            playerControl.DeathScript();
        }
    }
}
```

To actually make use of the decorator, you also need to figure out a way to get all objects in the project to use the decorator object instead of the original HealthSystem. One way to achieve this is with the [dependency injection pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). This way the clients using the IHealthSystem object don't need to know if they're working with the original or the decorator variant.

```
public class PlayerBuilder
{
    public static Player CreatePlayer()
    {
        Player player = new GameObject("Player").AddComponent<Player>();
        PlayerControl playerControl = player.AddComponent<PlayerControl>();
        IHealthSystem wrappedHealthSystem = new HealthSystem();
        IHealthSystem healthSystemDecorator = new HealthSystemDecorator(wrappedHealthSystem, playerControl);
        player.Init(healthSystemDecorator); // inject the decorator to the player object
    }
}
```

If you actually want to be able to just add attributes to methods to decorate them with additional functionality, then you should look into [code weaving](https://github.com/ByronMayne/Weaver).

Comment: `IHealthSystem healthSystem = new HealthSystem();    healthSystem = new HealthSystemDecorator(healthSystem, playerControl);` - I understand it, but I've got to say I had to stop for a second there. (Reassigning a variable right after passing its old value as a parameter, on the same line)

Comment: @Orion Yeah good point, I should have rather assigned HealthSystem to a variable called wrappedHealthSystem here as well. I'll edit the answer to make this change.